Error loading kera model ValueError: Could not interpret initializer identifier: {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'Orthogonal'
I've created an ltsm model in Colab and want to use that locally.
In colab:
model.save("my_model.keras")

And then locally my script is:
from keras.models import load_model
model_2 = load_model("my_model.keras")

But I get the error
ValueError: Could not interpret initializer identifier: {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'Orthogonal', 'config': {'gain': 1.0, 'seed': None}, 'registered_name': None, 'shared_object_id': 133617776692624}

After scratching around I learned about this:
from keras.initializers import Orthogonal

# Define a dictionary mapping the name 'Orthogonal' to the Orthogonal class
custom_objects = {'Orthogonal': Orthogonal}


# Load the model with the custom_objects parameter
model_2 = load_model("my_model.keras", custom_objects=custom_objects)


ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to LSTM: {'batch_input_shape': [None, 1, 6], 'time_major': False}

Are there any ways of saving the model in a format out from colab that I can import?
I also tried using pip freeze > requirements.txt to see if I could standardise the modules but to no avail.

Hey @elksie5000, were you able to figure out the issue or able to create a work around??

@Aditya. No, I'm afraid. I decided to try pytorch although its not working as well. All part of the learning curve, I guess.
